# Would like to see the email address from sender in the column

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to include the email address from the sender of the email to appear when I am looking through my inbox. Currently it only shows the from name, not the actual from email.

I have checked all the addable columns, but cannot seem to specifically also show the email address from the sender that I received the email from.

I am getting a lot of phishing emails so this helps also to quickly check before checking further.

Am I missing where this is?

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for May 2022, Thunderbird 91.9:

The add-on for this purpose is now [Full Address Column](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/full-address-column/).
([GitHub page](https://github.com/lkosson/full-address-column).)

Comment: Yes, this seem the preferred answer. Unfortunately, it remains a mystery why an add-on is needed for such an essential feature to detect spam easily. And this is even more of an issue, as this add-on needs a quite sensitive permission due to the internal Thunderbird design.

Comment: @AxelHeider I fully agree.  This has also always been the way the dreaded Outlook client worked (so that sender Bank Of America <boa4387213@sleazysite.ru> was shown simply as Bank Of America), and I always loathed it mainly for this reason.

Comment: ...aaaaand they borked it. These people hate addons.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't a feature included in Thunderbird. Addon is broken right now due to Thunderbird 115 update.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like to include the email address from the sender of the email to appear

It's not build in as far as I know. However there is an add-on "Show Address Only 0.2.0"

> **About this Add-on**
>
> Adds columns to display Sender/Recipients mail address only. The address book is not used, addresses are taken from letter header.
>
> 2019.09.21 - upgraded max version to 68.+
>
> 2018.09.02 - upgraded max version to 65.0

Caveat: I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will work with your version of Thunderbird.

Source: [Show Address Only :: Add-ons for Thunderbird](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/show-address-only/)

---

#### It is very odd that Thunderbird doesn't have such a basic feature included.

> As with other add-ons, it's a feature that is used by a relatively small number of users, and it probably rates as a lower priority compared to more essential developments for the program.

Source: [show sender email to detect forged sender | Thunderbird Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1233191)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it did not seem to work for my version, but a similar addon did.It is very odd that Thunderbird doesn't have such a basic feature included. I mean this seems to do the trick, but it means an extra column when it can be done with brackets such as Firstname Secondname (email@address.com). I am wondering if I can somehow edit the addon to also include the full name. Never done it before so not sure how hard it is.

Comment: "As with other add-ons, it's a feature that is used by a relatively small number of users, and it probably rates as a lower priority compared to more essential developments for the program." source [show sender email to detect forged sender | Thunderbird Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1233191)

Comment: I see where you got that quote from. Well I completely disagree with that comment. I don't think it's used by a relatively small number of users, rather it's forced because there is no option.

Comment: @zavakz "a similar addon did it".  Can you please share the name of the add-on?  I have the same need.

Comment: Stating "it's a feature that is used by a relatively small number of users" seems pure ignorance to me. And it creates a chicken-egg problem. At least for the spam folder, this seems an essential feature, it should be on my default to educate users.